# How can I use an image instead of a shape for a node in graph view in Soley Studio?

Tags: xml, view, graph, defineproperty, view-templates

I am setting up my graph view template in Soley Studio. In some pre-installed solutions I saw that nodes in graph view have been visualized with an icon or graphic instead of a circle, rectangle, etc.

I want to define my properties for a node class in such way, that it shows a gear icon or something similar. Which `<property>` do I have to use?

I copied one from another solution, but it does not change anything:

```
<Style DataSource=".ProdFunction" VisualTarget=”Node”>
<!-- View Properties --> 
<Properties>
<Property Name="StyleName" Value="ShapeOrImageNodeStyle" />
<Property Name="Image">
<Value IsReference="true">icon</Value>
</Property> 
<Property Name="ColorizeImage" Value = "false" />
<Property Name="Width" Value="60" />
<Property Name="Height" Value="60" /> 
</Properties>
</Style>
```

I wanted to use `<Property Name="Image"> <Value IsReference="true">icon</Value></Property>` . But nothing changes. How do I refer to the “icon” I want to have? Adding it to the Images folder did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `<Property Name="Image"> <Value IsReference="true">icon</Value></Property>` you are referring to an attribute `icon` of your node class `ProdFunction`. The value of this attribute would have to be the path to the image you want to use.
e.g. *images\gearicon.png* (a path from your project on is sufficient)

This way is very useful if you want to have different images/icons visualized for each instance of one class. 
In your case I would recommend you to simply define one image file for the whole node class. Then you also do not need to define an additional attribute for you `ProdFunction` class.

Your graph view template style may look like this in the end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<View Provider="Soley.Framework.AddIns.GraphDataViewProvider.GraphDataDisplayBinding">
      <References>
        <Reference Source="DataPresentation::ViewTemplates/Graph.slvt"/>
      </References>

    <Styles>
      <Style DataSource=".ProdFunction" VisualTarget=”Node”>

       <Properties>
         <Property Name="StyleName" Value="ShapeOrImageNodeStyle" />

         <Property Name="Image">
           <Value>images\gearicon.png</Value>
         </Property> 

         <Property Name="ColorizeImage" Value = "false" />

         <Property Name="Width" Value="60" />
         <Property Name="Height" Value="60" /> 
      </Properties>  

    </Style>
   </Styles>
</View>
```

Here is also a list with available view properties in Soley Studio: [Help Center - View Templates](https://support.soley.io/article-categories/view-templates/)